# Create new project option not showing in TFS Web Access

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

We recently moved our on-premise TFS server to a new server and we are able to access our projects on the new server.

However, I am unable to see the option to add a new project, only to browse to existing projects:

[image: Missing option]

I have checked my permissions and my permissions include:

- Team Foundation Administrator
- Project Collection Administrator

This should give me enough rights to add a new project. I'm sure I am missing something, but I cannot see what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online) you can create your projects from the web interface.

But in TFS you need to fire up a matching version of Visual Studio (in your case 2013), and create new projects from the Team Explorer window.

From Team Foundation Server 2015 update 2 onwards you'll be able to create team projects using the web interface. [With all older versions of TFS you need to follow these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181477%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that I cannot see the link to create a project in the TFS web interface.

Comment: That is correct, TFS doesn't have this functionality. You need to use Visual Studio 2013 to do it.

Comment: Thank you...I am mainly using VSTS these days and forgot the differences with on premise installations.